# How can iText embed font used by JFreeChart for chart title and labels?

Tags: pdf, itext, jfreechart

I'm using Linux machine with iText and JFreeChart. I noticed after embedding a chart that Helvetica font (un-embedded) now appears in the PDF file. Here's the code I'm using:

```
import com.itextpdf.text.Font;

// create chart using JFreeChart
final XYPlot plot = jchart.getXYPlot();
final LogAxis xAxis = new LogAxis("x axis");
final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis("y axis");
...
java.awt.Font cFont = new java.awt.Font("/home/fonts/jigsaw.otf",java.awt.Font.PLAIN,10);
xAxis.setLabelFont(cFont);  // set axis label font
...

// add chart to PDF
PdfTemplate chart = canvas.createTemplate(chartWidth, chartHeight);  
Graphics2D  g2d1 = new PdfGraphics2D(chart, chartWidth, chartHeight);
Rectangle2D r2d1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0,0,chartWidth,chartHeight);
jchart.draw(g2d1, r2d1); 
g2d1.dispose();
canvas.addTemplate(chart,document.left(),100);
```

The font jigsaw.otf is not observed in the PDF that gets created, although the font size of 10 (derived from `cFont`) is used (and changing this value does control the Helvetica font size that gets substituted here).

My ultimate goal is to embed all fonts. This means either (1) embedding jigsaw.otf so that Helvetica does not appear un-embedded, or (2) embedding Helvetica and forgetting about using jigsaw.oft. Either is acceptable, as long as I can control the font size used in the JFreeChart chart.

How to do it (simplest method)?

There's a section in iText book 2nd edition 14.5.2 "Drawing text to PdfGraphics2d", but I believe that is adding text to an existing graphic, rather than embedding the text used by JFreeChart in its chart. Correct me if I'm wrong. Quite confused. Hoping someone can provide a simple example how it's done.

Comment: You probably want to _embed a subset of the font_ (of used characters): `FontFactory.defaultEmbedding = true;`. If that works without JFreeChart, it probably also works with.

Answer (score 2):

Found the answer to my own question above in the iText book, 2nd edition, listing 14.20 "Text2ToPdf1.java".

One issue to be aware of is the use of `Font` class for java's AWT versus iText -- they both share the same Font class name, so be sure to keep them organized in your code (e.g. the linked `Font` in http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=254 for `import java.awt.Font;` points to `com.itextpdf.text.Font`). I've included the path `java.awt.Font` in the code below to avoid confusion:

```
  // Create a custom font mapper that forces Graphics2D to use a specific font
  FontMapper myChartFont = new FontMapper() {
      public BaseFont awtToPdf(java.awt.Font font) {
          try {
              return BaseFont.createFont("/path/to/your/font/myFontName.ttf",BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
          } catch (DocumentException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          return null;
      }

      public java.awt.Font pdfToAwt(BaseFont font, int size) {
          return null;
      }
  };

  ...
  // include code posted in original question here, with the following substitution:
  Graphics2D  g2d1 = new PdfGraphics2D(chartY, chartWidth, chartHeight, myChartFont);
  ...
```

This way the font is always embedded in the final PDF for all JFreeChart objects.

Thank you Bruno for writing an excellent book! http://itextpdf.com/book/